# Open number of files from folder into dataframes with similar names to later perform operations on these dataframes

Tags: r, csv

I have been trying to perform the same actions on different sets of data with the same variables. I need to be able to read in multiple csv files and put them in data frames with similar names (Ex: data1, data2, etc) so I can perform the same tasks on them. Currently I am rewriting the set of codes 5 times over, but if there is a way to name and loop through their names and perform these tasks, it would be nice. The problem is that the total number of files will not remain the same each time I execute the code.

Here is what I have tried so far and this might give an idea of what I need to do.

```
filenames <- dir(path="C/.../Files")
for(i in filenames){
  ori_data[i] <- read.table(i, header = T, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors=F)
}
```

Of course this throws an error because R does not recognize ori_data[i].
My Folder 'Files' only contains the csv files that need to be analysed. The number of files can be anywhere between 1 and 20. I just have no clue on how to name these dataframes.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How about `read.table(filenames[i], header = T, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors=F)`

Answer (score 1):

You can read the files into a list. Set your working directory to the folder containing the files of interest, and then do this:

```
ori_data <- lapply(dir(), read.csv, header = T, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = F)
```

If you want to look at the `ith` data frame, then you can do so by entering `ori_data[i]`.

You can also name the list components like this:

```
names(ori_data) <- dir()
```

---

To address the error that you're getting, you haven't already allocated space for `ori_data` yet, I would assume. For example, `ori_data[i]` could end up being something like `ori_data["file.txt"]`, assuming that file.txt is one of the files named by `dir()`. If you haven't already initialized `ori_data` as a data frame or list, then R won't be able to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `assign`.  Something like this should work for you:

```
    filenames <- dir(path="C/.../Files")
for(i in filenames){
  assign(paste0('ori_data_',i),read.table(i, header = T, sep = ",",stringsAsFactors=F))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach but I can't guarantee it works well. Give it a try and let us know. The approach is to create an empty data frame and then create a loop to eat all the cvs in the directory, with names stored (with the option `full.names = TRUE`) in a file.

```
data <- data.frame()
filesf <- list.files("your_directory", full.names=TRUE)
for (i in filesf) {
     data <- rbind(data, read.csv(filesf[i]))
}
```

After that you should have a unique file called `data`. you can then split that files with `split` of with `dplyr` function `group_by`.